# define a regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regular expressions in python to say a 4 characters string with 1st character being a digit and 3 other characters being either a digit or a capital letter.
Here's examples of patterns that should match 1CTT, 2IR8, 35TR, 4T1R

I tried many ways, here's the last code I tried :

```
exp=re.compile("[0-9]{1}([A-Z0-9]{3})")
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: That sure looks like it ought to have worked (even though the first `{1}` is obsolete, and you could have used `\d` and `\u`). What is the problem with this expression?

Comment: You only need to add anchors to figure the start and end of the string, `{1}` is useless, remove it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I don't think this needs anchors when used on each pattern separately. – Ah wait: you mean it will *also* incorrectly match something like `?wotthis0ABC`. Right.

Comment: @RadLexus: yes It's  what I mean. (as an aside `{1}` is not obsolete, `{1}` is and has ever been useless (redundant))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you've tried last, looks correct and should match the provided test strings. Though you don't have to specify `{1}` and there is no need for a capturing group (the parenthesis):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "text, 1CTT, 2IR8, 35TR, 4T1R, smth else"
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"[0-9][A-Z0-9]{3}")
>>> pattern.findall(text)
['1CTT', '2IR8', '35TR', '4T1R']
```

You might need to additionally add the *word boundary* constraint (thanks to @Jon Clements):

```
>>> text = "text, 1CTT, 2IR8, 35TR, 4T1R, smth else, 35TT35XYZ"
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"\b[0-9][A-Z0-9]{3}\b")
>>> pattern.findall(text)
['1CTT', '2IR8', '35TR', '4T1R']
```

Comment: Try with `text = "text, 1CTT, 2IR8, 35TR, 4T1R, smth else, 35TT35XYZ"` :)

Comment: @JonClements oh no, don't do this to me :) Okay, let me fix that. Thanks.